# jQuery get results from *all* link header pages into one callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, gitlab

I'm trying to get a list of *all* code snippets of a GitLab (not GitHub!) project. The [GitLab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/snippets.html) provides allows me to collect at most 100 snippets per call, but provides Link Headers for the other (`next`,`prev`,`first` and `last`) pages ([see this part of GitLab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#pagination-link-header)).

What is the best way to perform asynchronous jQuery.get calls to all the pages and then pass all results in a single callback function?

Neither of the two ideas I have come up with seem very attractive:

- Make a dummy call for the first page to get the total number of pages (`X-Total-Pages` in getResponseHeader), then generate all `jQuery.get`s and pass them to `jQuery.when`. Not too bad, but the call to the first page is wasted.
- Run the `jQuery.get`s in a while loop and have each of them store its data to some global variable before launching the callback on that global variable. Disadvantage is that calls are not run in parallel and the global variable does not look like a clean solution.

Since I think this should be a somewhat common problem I was hoping there would be a clean solution somewhere?

**EDIT**
Here is an implementation of the first idea, to illustrate what I am asking for, namely how to avoid the first `$.getJSON` call whose results are not used?

```js
function getAllSnippets(callback){

    //Make a dummy call to get number of pages 
    data = {"private_token": "my_private_token", "per_page": 100, "page":1}
    $.when(
      $.getJSON("https://myserver/api/snippets",data)
    ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    
        //Get the number of pages
        numPages = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('X-Total-Pages')
        console.log(numPages+' pages in total')

        //Generate queries for each new page
        var promises = [];
        for (var iPage = 1; iPage < numPages+1; iPage++) {
            data = {"private_token": "my_private_token", "per_page": 100, "page":iPage}
            promises.push($.getJSON("https://myserver/api/snippets",data));
        }

        //Collect and merge results from all calls
        Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
           answers = []
           for  (var iPage = 0; iPage < numPages; iPage++){
               answers = $.merge( answers, results[iPage] );
            }
          callback(answers);
        }, function(err) {
          alert("Failed to collect code snippets"+err);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The second approach makes no sense since your `while` loop would lock the user interface without knowing the number of pages and when to stop. You should also read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask